# Get orgUnitId from a Course Name in Valence

Tags: php, get, desire2learn, valence

I'm trying to retrieve the orgUnitId of a course from the full course name 
(ie: `CHM-1210-01 - General Chemistry I`). Any suggestions on how to get the orgUnitId from this?

I've tried `/d2l/api/lp/(version)/courses/?Name=CHM-1210-01 - General Chemistry I` and `/d2l/api/lp/(version)/courses/?Name=CHM-1210-01%20-%20General%20Chemistry%20I` with no success.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

--Valence Newbie

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/

http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/orgunit.html#get--d2l-api-lp-(version)-orgstructure-

It has options for OrgUnitType (set to whatever your orgUnitTypeId is for courses) and orgUnitName which would be your course name. Then it would return matching org units.

Comment: I tried `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/orgstructure/?Name=CHM-1210-01 - General Chemistry I` but still no results. As I mentioned in my original post, I need to be able to get the identifier from the name; how can I use the name with `GET /d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/` to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation the query parameter you should be using is "orgUnitName" (not "Name").

Comment: So I've tried: `/d2l/api/lp/(version)/courses/?orgUnitName=CHM-1210-01 - General Chemistry I` and `/d2l/api/lp/(version)/orgstructure/?orgUnitName=CHM-1210-01 - General Chemistry I`. Neither produce results; I think it might be because of the spaces in the course names?